# Exporting format for csv in hive

Tags: hive, hue

I am running Hive 1.2. I have seen that to download a table I use

```
insert overwrite directory '/user/table' 
row format delimited 
fields terminated by ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
select * from mytable.table;
```

That works but I see that it downloads slighted differently when I just use the GUI in HUE.

I am downloading useragent fields in weblogs and the difference is here:

Downloading through the hive query and hadoop fs I get

> ["Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36"]

Downloading through HUE I get

> "[""Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36""]"

I prefer the format with the double quotes. What is called and how can I change  my Hive query to get the quotes in this format?

thanks!

Comment: My guess: `HUE` treat the result as string, so added the quotes while downloading. In short, `HUE` did some `transformation`, while `hadoop fs` didn't. So changing the `hive` query won't help.  Why do you need quotes in your result?

Comment: I am using a python UserAgent parser. It seems to have trouble with the data when the quote was missing so I wanted to try and get it in that format. Is there a regex solution to adding it or a way to specify the type to get the quotes?

Comment: You mean you have trouble using python reading the file?

Comment: I am using a function that reads the string. It seems to do its job when the double quotes are there and seems to miss things when they are not there

Comment: Show the code and sample input in the file you are trying to read.